# Gatsby.js - Responsive images using gatsby-image and gatsby-transformer-sharp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've read what I could about how to create responsive images with different sizes in gatsby.js

I managed to do that for small devices and it works good but on a desktop, the image is not contained in the parent container and resized but it is shown as full size.

This is my query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on ImageSharp {
            fluid {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    fluidImages: file(relativePath: { regex: "/web-development/" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(duotone: { highlight: "#f00e2e", shadow: "#192550" }) {
          base64
          aspectRatio
          src
          srcSet
          srcWebp
          sizes
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This is my code for displaying the image:

```
const { data } = this.props
const webdev = data.fluidImages.childImageSharp.fluid
<picture>
    <source srcSet={webdev.srcSet} sizes={webdev.sizes}/>
    <img alt="Web Development" src={webdev.src} />
</picture>
```

Once again mobile is resizing great but desktop is showing full size image that breaks everything.

Best regards

Comment: I found the problem. For gatsby v2 all packages related to image-processing should be for v2.
    yarn add gatsby-image@next gatsby-plugin-sharp@next gatsby-transformer-sharp@next

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
export default props => {
  const { fluid } = props.data.fluidImage.childImageSharp

  return (

<div style={{ maxHeight: "100%" }}>
        <Img
          fluid={fluid}
          style={{ maxHeight: "100%" , height: "100vh" }}
           imgStyle={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
        />
        </div>

...
```

must replicate the behavior of class = "img-fluid" in bootstrap 4